# Unobtrusive Google Analytics Event Tracking not working

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

I know this is not the only question out there, but I still couldn't find a hint on what's wrong.

The javascript:

```
$(function()
{
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-[FILTERED]-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; 
  ga.async = true;
  ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);


    $('a[href$=pdf]').each( function() { $(this).attr('target', '_blank'); });
    $('a[href$=pdf]').on('click', function()    { _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Link', 'Click', $(this).attr('href'), 1]); });

});
```

SO, when inspecting *the generated source code* (through the webdevelopment toolbar in FF), the javascript libraries are inserted in the following order:

1. ga
2. jquery
3. the page js with the content seen above (1:1)

I don't get any errors in firebug, page tracking is working fine and inserting debug output after the `.push` also works, so no "ghost stop".

I tried to click some pdf files every day for 3 days, and there is nothing in GA registered.

Any ideas?

---

**edit**
I tried to debug it with `ga_debug.js`. Firebug shows the requested images for  `_trackPageview`, but not for  `_trackEvent`. So I tried the following:

```
$('a[href$=pdf]').each( function() 
{ 
    $(this).attr('target', '_blank'); 
    $(this).attr('onClick', "javascript:_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Link', 'Click', $(this).attr('href'), 1]);");
});
```

Now the images is requested, but according to firebug, loads forever and won't complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, apparently you cannot oursource the `_gaq` part into a file and include it. Adding it directly into the html template works.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most common problems is the analytics tracking GIF request not completing before leaving the current page -- You're adding a `target='_blank'` attribute, so that shouldn't be a problem here.

Have you tried using [ga_debug.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/articles/gaTrackingTroubleshooting#gaDebug), or [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to make sure the request is being sent?

Comment: Right, that's why I've chosen the `target="_blank"` approach over the one setting a timeout. Didn't know about the debug js_will try that and get back, thanks.